# Testing an Interface with jUnit

Tags: java, junit, interface

I have an Interface and a class which implements it. 
I @Override the method and I want to test it using JUnit4.
I don't know if I have an error on my method or if I'm doing something wrong in my test class.

Is it correct to have an instance of the interface itself, or should I make it an instance of the myCustomString Class which implements the Interface.

if anyone could explain how the objects are calling each other that would be awesome.

My JUnit test returns a null pointer exception.

```
public interface MyCustomStringInterface {
    int countNumbers();
}

public class MyCustomString implements MyCustomStringInterface {
    private String string;



    @Override
    public int countNumbers() {
        while (string.length() != 0 ) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
                if(Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
        return 0;
}

public class MyCustomStringTest { 
    private MyCustomStringInterface mycustomstring;

    @Test
    public void testCountNumbers1() {
       mycustomstring.setString("th1s strin8 shou1d hav3 numb3rs, 
       righ7?");

       assertEquals(6, mycustomstring.countNumbers());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you testing only those members for which the class adheres to the Interface?

Comment: I forgot to mention I also have this method
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mycustomstring = new MyCustomString();
    }

Comment: Well, according to the code you posted, you didn't create a `MyCustomString` object.  That's probably the source of your `NullPointerException`.

Comment: should i create that object in the MyCustomString class itself

Comment: Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to the code you posted, you didn't create a `MyCustomString` object.  That's probably the source of your `NullPointerException`.

Try adding `mycustomstring = new MyCustomString()` right above your setString method, like this:

```
public class MyCustomStringTest { 
    private MyCustomStringInterface mycustomstring;

    @Test
    public void testCountNumbers1() {
    mycustomstring = new MyCustomString();
       mycustomstring.setString("th1s strin8 shou1d hav3 numb3rs, righ7?");

       assertEquals(6, mycustomstring.countNumbers());
    }   
}
```

Comment: yea i forgot to mention i added that to a @before method

Comment: i no longer have the NullPointerException. but the test is failing anyway, so i think there is something wrong with my CountNumbers method